# All content is displayed in one row rather than in the rows they should be in

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table where it is scrollable with fixed table headers, the problem is that all the table rows are displayed under the first column (question No). Why is this happening. I can't show what it exactly looks like on page because server is down but I can show you Jsfiddle of my code which is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8hNwG/9/)

How can all of the content be displayed in their correct rows and not all the content displayed in one row which is the first row?

Comment: It looks like all the columns are in the right place, but aren't populated. Please correct me if I'm wrong on that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want one table cell to span the width of many columns, in which case you'd use `colspan="#"` where `#` is the number of columns the cell should span.

Comment: Well what happened before I inserted a div to make table scrollable, all the content were in the correct columns, but when I included the div to make the table scrollable, then all the content go into one column

Answer (score 0):

The columns just aren't styled correctly, but they are in the right place. Add the css code:

```
.optionAndAnswer td {
    border:1px solid black;     
}
```